# Not Working - Open native Front Camera through Intent as default in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, native, front-camera

In my app I want to open native front camera as default as it my requirement.
I tried putExtras and send it as intent but it is not working as below :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_CAMERA);
```

Can you please help me out as it is my app requirement?

Thanks

Comment: did you add permission in your mainfest file

Comment: plz post your full code of firing intent

Comment: @YounasBangashyes for camera i have added. Which else permission need to be added for front camera?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is a hack. It is using a testing code of the Camera app. 
And i guess it was disabled from Android L. Go for fetching instance of front facing camera and loading in your own view.

```
Camera c = null;  // object that use
Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
int count = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

for (int i = 0; i<cameraCount; i++) {
     Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
     try {
        c = Camera.open(i);
     } catch (RuntimeException e) {
       // Handle
     }
   }
}
```

This code will fetch front facing camera's object and you can use it for your purpose.